Programming a Datalogger - Won't create file
Context: I'm building a project for university and programming is not really my "field of expertise". It is a GUI built on C# (Visual Studio).
Porblem: I tried making a datalogger which should register everything the user does (along with a time stamp) and save it in a .csv file, but I can't seem to get the program to create it. It should show up on my desktop once I close the app, and have a record of the things I did. If anyone here could just check out and "see if it makes sense", maybe point out where it's wrong, that would be great.
PD: English isn't my first language, sorry.
This is the code where I think lays the error:
using ClosedXML.Excel;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Diagrams;

namespace Proyecto_controlLed_Servo
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private List<string> receivedDataList = new List<string>();
        private bool _isRunning = true;

        public Form1()
        {
            CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
            receivedDataList = new List<string>();

            SP1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(SP1_DataReceived);
            SP1.ErrorReceived += new SerialErrorReceivedEventHandler(SP1_ErrorReceived);
            SP1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
            LogAlert("Aplicación iniciada");
        }

        private void bCon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!SP1.IsOpen)
                {
                    SP1.PortName = CBPort.Text;
                    SP1.Open();
                    LogAlert("Conexión Establecida");
                    receivedDataList.Add("Conexión al puerto COM establecida.");

                    PBConexion.Value = 100;
                    enableComponents();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error al conectarse al puerto: " + error.Message);
            }
        }

        private void bDis_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (SP1.IsOpen)
            {
                try
                {
                    //Enviar comando para apagar steppers y cerrar puerto COM
                    SP1.WriteLine("l");
                    SP1.Close();
                    LogAlert("Gimb-App desconectado");
                    receivedDataList.Add("Se ha desconectado del puerto COM.");

                    MessageBox.Show("Entrada COM desconectada");
                    PBConexion.Value = 0;
                    labelEstado.Text = "Estado actual: Desconectado";
                }
                catch (Exception error)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error al desconectar el puerto: " + error.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        private void BRef_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
                CBPort.Items.Clear();
                CBPort.Items.AddRange(ports);
                if (ports.Length > 0)
                {
                    CBPort.SelectedIndex = 0;
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Lista de puertos actualizada");
                receivedDataList.Add("Se refrescó la lista de puertos COM.");
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error al refrescar la lista de puertos: " + error.Message);
            }
        }

        //Método para registrar alertas
        private void LogAlert(string message)
        {
            string timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            receivedDataList.Add($"{timestamp}:{message}");
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (SP1.IsOpen)
            {
                try
                {
                    SP1.WriteLine("l");
                    SP1.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception error)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error al cerrar la aplicación: " + error.Message);
                }
            }
            _isRunning = false;
            SaveDataToCsv();
        }

        private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!_isRunning) return;

            try
            {
                string data = SP1.ReadLine();
                receivedDataList.Add("Dato recibido: " + data);
                Console.WriteLine("Dato recibido: " + data);
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                receivedDataList.Add("Error al recibir datos: " + error.Message);
            }
        }

        private void SaveDataToCsv()
        {
            try
            {
                string desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
                string filePath = Path.Combine(desktopPath, "RegistroGimb.csv");
                string csvFilePath = Path.ChangeExtension(filePath, ".csv");

                using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook())
                {
                    var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Registros");
                    worksheet.Cell(1, 1).Value = "Registro de Actividades";
                    for (int i = 0; i < receivedDataList.Count; i++)
                    {
                        worksheet.Cell(i + 2, 1).Value = receivedDataList[i];
                    }

                    workbook.SaveAs("RegistroGimb.xlsx"); //guardar como archivo .xlsx
                }

                ConvertXlsxToCsv(filePath, csvFilePath);

                MessageBox.Show("Registro de alertas guardado en {filePath}");
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error al escribir en el archivo de registro: " + error.Message);
            }
        }

        private void ConvertXlsxToCsv(string filePath, string csvFilePath)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook(filePath))
                {
                    var worksheet = workbook.Worksheet(1);

                    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(csvFilePath))
                    {
                        foreach (var row in worksheet.RowsUsed())
                        {
                            var cells = row.CellsUsed().Select(c => c.GetValue<string>());
                            var line = string.Join(",", cells);
                            writer.WriteLine(line);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error al convertir el archivo a CSV: " + error.Message);
            }
        }

        //Método para lectura de puerto serie
        private void SP1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string data = SP1.ReadLine();

                if (data.Contains("Movimiento detectado"))
                {
                    LogAlert("Movimiento detectado");
                }
                else if (data.Contains("Motor endendido"))
                {
                    LogAlert("Motor encendido");
                }
                else if (data.Contains("Motor apagado"))
                {
                    LogAlert("Motor apagado");
                }
                else if (data.Contains("Conexión establecida"))
                {
                    LogAlert("Conexión establecida");
                }
                else if (data.Contains("Desconexion"))
                {
                    LogAlert("Desconexión del puerto COM");
                }
                else
                {
                    LogAlert("Dato recibido: " + data);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error al leer datos del puerto serie: " + error.Message);
                LogAlert("Error al leer datos del puerto serie: " + error.Message);
            }
        }



Please read How to debug small programs. Step through the program line by line and verify it's doing what you expect.

In addition to StevePy 's answer: 1. Consider using an actual logger (ILogger). That way you can relatively easily change log targets. 2. If you want to write/read CSV consider a CSV Helper Library. 3. Maybe consider logging with semantic logging to a DB (SQLite?) and extract what you need later.

Hey @Fildor, thanks for the advice. The only issue is that we are required to have everything (or at least most things) built into the app and get it to work without using any sort of "external help" (like a program that stores data and then turns it into an excel file and so on).
PD: A big "THANK YOU" to StevePy, you wonderful human being.

I can see a few problems. First, start small rather than trying to tackle something "complete". If you want to save a CSV file, it is just a comma-delimited file so there is no need to create an Excel document. You are introducing steps there that are just going to get you lost. For instance you are creating the Excel document and saving it via:

workbook.SaveAs("RegistroGimb.xlsx")


... but then you want to convert that to CSV you are passing:
string desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
string filePath = Path.Combine(desktopPath, "RegistroGimb.csv");
string csvFilePath = Path.ChangeExtension(filePath, ".csv");

ConvertXlsxToCsv(filePath, csvFilePath);

Notice that your "filePath" is not the filename you saved the XLSX as, and may not be in the Desktop folder. By default files will get saved in the working folder which is typically the same folder your app is running in.
Saving a CSV in the simplest way is as easy as opening a file reader and writing the lines with any values separated by commas. Since your "alerts" are a single string this is very simple:
string desktopFilePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "RegistroGimb.csv");
StringBuilder output = new();
output.AppendLine("Registro de Actividades"); // Header
output.AppendLine(string.Empty);  // blank line
foreach(var line in receivedDataList)
    output.AppendLine(line);

File.WriteAllText(desktopFilePath, output.ToString());

That will write the output to a CSV on your desktop. This will overwrite any existing RegistroGimb.csv file with each run. You can check for the existence of a file and use AppendAllText to append to an existing file.
string desktopFilePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "RegistroGimb.csv");
StringBuilder output = new();
bool isNewFile = !File.Exists(desktopFilePath);

if (isNewFile)
{   // Add header only if creating a new file.
    output.AppendLine("Registro de Actividades"); // Header 
    output.AppendLine(string.Empty);  // blank line
}
foreach(var line in receivedDataList)
    output.AppendLine(line);

if (isNewFile)
    File.WriteAllText(desktopFilePath, output.ToString());
else
    File.AppendAllText(desktopFilePath, output.ToString());

No need to mess with Excel documents. Excel will recognize and open CSV files.
